# Maintainability issue of refactoring "fA()" and "fB()" to "fAB(){return report;}"

Tags: c++, architecture, maintainability

When my program is very young, there are usually many functions that do simple things.

When it became older, I found that it is more convenient to bundle some similar functions together, and group the return results of old functions as a "Report".

The "Report" can be easily passed around as a communication package among different modules.

### Example 1

**Code V1**

```
class B{
    float getWidth(C c){ 
        float width= ... (very cheap function about "c") ;
        return width;
    }
    float getHeight(C c){
        float height= ... (very cheap function about "c") ;
        return height;
    }
};
```

**Code V2**

```
class ReportSize { float width; float height; }
class B{
    ReportSize getSize(C c){   //<-- grouped
        float width = ... ;
        float height= ... ;
        return ReportSize(width ,height);
    }
};
```

### Example 2

**Code V1**

```
class D{
    Vector3 calculateNarrow(){ ... }
    Vector3 calculateBoard(){ ... }
};
```

**Code V2**

```
class ReportVector3Pair{
    Vector3 resultNarrow;
    Vector3 resultBoard;
    Vector3 get(NARROW_OR_BOARD paramEnum){
        //return "resultNarrow" or "resultBoard"
    } 
};
class D{
    ReportVector3Pair calculate(){ ... }  //<-- grouped
};
```

### Question

The refactoring cost some development time. All locations of code (up to 100 callers) have to be manually refactored to match the new signature.

How to minimize the chance of the need to refactor it later? How to minimize cost of the refactoring if it may happen in future?

Comment: I recommend the book [Clean Code: A Handbook of Agile Software Craftsmanship (by Robert C Martin)](http://ptgmedia.pearsoncmg.com/images/9780132350884/samplepages/9780132350884.pdf) (notice that this link just refers to a PDF with just few free sample chapters - the complete book is availably in good bookstores or online vendors)

Comment: If width/height pairs are things you'll be passing around frequently then declaring a type for that isn't a bad plan. I'd use `struct` in preference to `class` as that implies it's just a basic structure, nothing fancy. The second example looks strange, but maybe additional context will help clarify. Abstraction is something you apply for a reason, not just because.

Comment: @Christoph Bimminger Which chapter or what is the name of the chapter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to minimize the chance of the need to refactor it later?

Create non-member functions that can return higher level objects instead of changing existing classes.

For example, instead of writing V2 of `B`, keep the existing `B` and use:

```
class ReportSize { float width; float height; }
ReportSize getReportSize(B const& b, C c)
{
   return {b.getWidth(c), b.getHeight(c)}
}
```

Similarly, instead of creating V2 of `D`, keep existing `D` and use:

```
Vector3 calculate(D const& d, NARROW_OR_BOARD paramEnum) {
   //return "resultNarrow" or "resultBoard"
}
```

> How to minimize cost of the refactoring if it may happen in future?

Use non-member functions to extend functionality instead of modifying existing classes.

According to Scott Meyers, [using non-member functions improves encapsulation.](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/how-non-member-functions-improve-encapsu/184401197)

Using non-member functions to add new functionality also follows [The Open/Closed Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle).